# Checking for a null (or no result) from dataset

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm working with the following bit of code in VisualBasic.NET. It's essentially supposed to be pulling a row ID from the table with specific conditions in mind. However, I would like to set up a failsafe of getting around those conditions if need be.

I'm trying to write an `If` statement to compare the `Item(0)` against but this bit of code seems to trigger no matter what. How can I compare to see if the Query being written as `QuestionConnectionQuery` is actually returning rows?

```vb
    For i As Integer = 1 To intNoOfQuestions
        'TODO: If there are no valid questions, pull up any of them that meets the difficulty requirement....


        ' Go into the Database and retrieve a question that hasn't been selected in the last seven days.
        Dim QuestionConnectionQuery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Questions.QuestionID, Questions.QuestionCategory & ' :   ' & Questions.QuestionSubCategory AS Category FROM Questions WHERE (((Questions.QuestionDifficulty)=[?])) OR (((Questions.LastDateRevealed) Is Null)) OR ((Questions.LastDateRevealed)>=DateAdd('d',-7,Now())) ORDER BY Rnd(QuestionID);", QuestionConnection)
        QuestionConnectionQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", intQuestionDifficulty(i - 1).ToString)
        Dim QuestionDataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(QuestionConnectionQuery)
        Dim QuestionDataSet As New DataSet

        QuestionDataAdapter.Fill(QuestionDataSet, "Questions")

        ' If the result is not null... add it to the array.
        If IsNothing(QuestionDataSet.Tables("Questions").Rows(0).Item(0)) Then
            ' Add that to the intQuestArray() array
            intQuestArray(i - 1) = QuestionDataSet.Tables("Questions").Rows(0).Item(0)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Not enough questions.")

            QuestionDataAdapter.Fill(QuestionDataSet, "Questions")

        End If


        ' Update the database by adding today's date to the "LastDateRevealed" column of the table.
        Dim QuestionUpdateQuery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE Questions SET LastDateRevealed=NOW() WHERE QuestionID = [?]", QuestionConnection)
        QuestionUpdateQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", QuestionDataSet.Tables("Questions").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString)
        QuestionUpdateQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next
```

Comment: In C# you would check against DbNull.Value instead of null (nothing in VB?) for SQL data, so that may be your issue with the if statement. I just don't know VB enough to say for sure.

Comment: That's what I'm using for the compare statement in the `IF(IsNothing())` but it seems to still trigger the Else statement, even if there is something chosen.

Comment: Show us the IsNothing function then.  Honestly, it's usually easier to use an OleDbDataReader, since you're probably going to loop through results anyway, and it's a far lighter-weight object, but that's just my opinion.  Ultimately, to check how many rows were returned, check the count of rows in your DataTable. If it's 0, you got nothing back.

Comment: @dodexahedron: Line 13?

Comment: Ah. Built-in VB function. My apologies. IsNothing does not compare against DBNull.  It only compares against Nothing, which is explicitly null in .Net. DBNull.Value is not Nothing - it is a special value that represents a null result from a database. The two comparisons are therefore not equivalent.  The answer given in the first comment is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
If IsDBNull(QuestionDataSet.Tables("Questions").Rows(0).Item(0)) Then
```

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: This would just have to be changed to If Not IsDBNull .... since I'm trying to see if it is not null before doing something...